# How to create field from substring of another field in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, substring

I need to create a new field from a substring (two characters string) of another field in MongoDB.
Help me, please.

Example:

```
field1  field2
abcdef  ab
qwerty  qw
opuytj  op
```

My code:

```
db.mycollection.update({}, {$set : {"field2": { $substr: [ {"field1"}, 0, 2 ] } }},
                        {upsert:false, multi:true})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have mongodb server v4.2 or newer you can do it easily like so:

```java
db.mycollection.updateMany({}, [
    {
        "$set": {
            "field2": {
                "$substr": ["$field1", 0, 2]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

the above was generated using the following c# code:

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Item : Entity
    {
        public string field1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            (new[] {
              new  Item {field1 = "abcdef"},
              new  Item {field1 = "qwerty"},
              new  Item {field1 = "opuytj"}
            }).Save();

            DB.Update<Item>()
              .Match(_ => true)
              .WithPipelineStage("{$set : { field2 : { $substr: [ '$field1', 0, 2 ] } }}")
              .ExecutePipeline();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the Mongo shell i received: 
Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators

Comment: is your mongo version 4.2 or above? more info [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/command/update/index.html#update-with-aggregation-pipeline).

Comment: Yes. Version 4.2.2.

Comment: @AndreVieiradeLima in that case the above query should work. it works on my machine. make sure your mongo shell is also > 4.2

Comment: For anyone else running into problems, remember the outer set of [ ] , which I overlooked

Answer (score 0):

Please use **find** with **forEach** keyword

```
db.demo.find({}).forEach( function(myDoc) { 
    var condname=myDoc.name;
    var condcat=myDoc.category;
    var replaceName =condcat.substring(0,2);

   db.demo.update({_id: myDoc._id}, {$set : {"name": replaceName }},
                        {upsert:false, multi:true}) 

} );
```

Comment: In the Mongo shell i received: TypeError: condname.substring is not a function